# How to vertically align an inline image with inline text following it?

Tags: css

Is there any way to vertically align an image element generated by a "content" property as part of a ":before" selector, next to adjacent inline text? In other words, I have

```
<a href="..." class="facebook">Share on Facebook</a>
```

As I don't want to pollute my markup with unnecessary IMG elements that only have to do with style, I resort to adding a small icon to the left of the link, via CSS (except that it does not align properly, hence the question):

```
a.facebook:before
{
     content: url(/style/facebook-logo.png);
}
```

I tried adding a "vertical-align: middle" (one of the most notoriously difficult aligning concepts to grasp in CSS, in my opinion, is that very property) but it has no effect. The logo aligns with text baseline, and I don't want to hardcode pixel offsets, because frankly text size differs from browser to browser, etc. Is there any solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, instead I'd use a `background-image`:

HTML:

```
<a href="..." class="facebook">Share on Facebook</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.facebook
{
    background-image: url(/style/facebook-logo.png);
    background-position: TOP LEFT;
    background-repeat:NO-REPEAT;
    padding-left:20px; /* or whatever the width of facebook-logo.png is */
}
```

If you're really married to the idea of using `:before` then you can use positioning:

```
a.facebook
{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    padding-left:20px; /* or whatever the width of facebook-logo.png is */
}
a.facebook:before
{
   content: url(/style/facebook-logo.png);
   position:absolute;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
}
```

Comment: Then the same problem with hardcoding pixel values appears - I hold no guarantees about the width of the logo image. It may be scaled as part of browser rendering... Would that not mess up the layout above? Of course, I just may have to bite the bullet here...

Comment: I don't think that would be an issue; the text size differs, but the image size doesn't... ?

Comment: @downvoter - Thanks; I missed a big mistake in my CSS selector. (whoops!)

Comment: I'm the downvoter : it was my mistake first and then what I believe is a bug from SO that blocked me from un-downvoting you. You had to edit in order to authorize me to un-downvote. Sorry!

Comment: @Felipe - np; like I said there was an error in my CSS which I hadn't caught :D

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen - Fantastic, even *you* can learn from my mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

Vertical-align only aplies to table-cell elements.
you can add a display:table-cell to "a.facebook"

Comment: IE7 and below won't understand that. I can't remember for IE8.  
@Poliveira vertical-align applies to block and inline-block too.

Comment: ... does IE7 respect `:before` rules?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a few transparent pixels above (or below) the logo, it's the simplest thing to do with images.

Otherwise you can play with **`line-height`**, but I wish you good luck to understand clearly what you're doing ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Aligning generated content vertically</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen,projection">

a, a:before {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}

a {
    vertical-align: super;
    line-height: 3;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-top: 1px solid darkred;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

a:before {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    line-height: 1;
    content: 'bottom  :';
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p><a href="#">Share sth with people you didn't think they'd have access to it</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can uncomment `display: inline-block;` too

Answer (score 0):

Line-height and a background-image will get you what you want:

CSS:

```
a.share-on-facebook {
    background: url(facebook.png) no-repeat top left;
    line-height: 40px; /* height of facebook logo */
    padding-left: 40px; /* width of Facebook logo */
}
```

Mark-up:

```
<a class="share-on-facebook" href="...">Share on Facebook</a>
```